# android image slide from a side

Tags: android, image, gallery

I have implemented a gallery where on touch the image is displayed at the centre of the screen

Now the image just pops up. How can i get the effect of image coming fro left or right of the screen, a sliding effect

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip" ></ImageView>
    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gallery" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:paddingLeft="0dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

adapter code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

    return imageView;
}
```

gallery activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdaptor(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) 
                    findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            image.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We will need to see some code of how you are creating the gallery.

Comment: So whats the scroll behavior now since you want it to go from left to right?

Comment: its not the scroll behaviour i had mentioned. when i click an image on the gallery, that image is displayed above the gallery in the image view. Now that image, instead of just popping up, i want it get the offect of "coming from left / right "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution i found

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Animation exitAnimation;

            if(position<positionLastCLicked){
             exitAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    GalleryActivity.this, R.layout.image_slidefromleft);}
            else{
                 exitAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        GalleryActivity.this, R.layout.image_slidefromright);
            }
            positionLastCLicked = position;
            image.startAnimation(exitAnimation);
            Utils.imageLoader.DisplayImage(galleryList.get(position)
                    .getImage(), image);
        }
```

slidefromleft.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="400" 
    android:fillEnabled="true" 
    android:fillAfter="true">
</translate>
```